# Can someone explain Magento 2 file execution

Tags: magento-2.1

I don't have knowledge in Magento 1. I have started to learn Magento 2, I want to know which file runs first when I go to: `http://localhost/magento/mymodule`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick answer, the first file is: [index.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/index.php#L39)

*Below some links and explanations...*

### Routing processing

Routing is processed in the following way:

- Modules provide information on their routers through the routerList
  parameter of `Magento\Framework\App\RouterList` type in `di.xml`.
- FrontController obtains active routers and checks whether a request can be processed.
- If a request cannot be processed by any router, the default router is used.
- If a request can be processed by a router, the router finds a route with matching frontName and looks through corresponding modules. If a module has matching controller and action names, a router instantiates this controller.

The `dispatch()` method of the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class requests an instance and returns its response.

For this class, the `Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface` processes the requests through its actions. Also, the following classes participate in processing the requests:

- The [`Magento\Framework\App\State`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/State.php) class provides information on the state of the application, that is, current mode, installation date, and so on.
- The [`Magento\Framework\App\Arealist`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/AreaList.php) class serves to configure the application areas through the `di.xml` file
- The [`Magento\App\Area\FrontNameResolverInterface`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Area/FrontNameResolverInterface.php) class resolves the dynamic area’s front names

### Default router

If a request cannot be processed by any router, the [`Magento\App\Framework\Router\DefaultRouter`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/DefaultRouter.php) default router lists handlers for processing such request.

[`Magento\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/NoRouteHandlerInterface.php) contains the list of handlers.

**Related informations**

- See the flowchart (from [atwix.com](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/request-flow-overview/)) below with the summarized information about the request execution flow.

  [image: Magento 2 request flowchart]
- See [The Route Config Kata](http://vinaikopp.com/2016/03/21/05_the_route_config_kata) by [Vinai Kopp](http://vinaikopp.com/blog/list).
- See [Routing in Magento 2](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/) by [Zoran Salamun](http://inchoo.net/author/zoran-salamun/profile/).
- See [Routing (devdocs)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/routing.html) by [Thomas Dobbs](https://github.com/tdobbs), [James Calcaben](https://github.com/jcalcaben), [Vincent MARMIESSE](https://github.com/VincentMarmiesse), [Mehryar Mansoor](https://github.com/mmansoorebay).